# How to determine memory corruption in web app deployed to T/C 6?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat

JSF 1.1 (yes, I know - legacy) app, with Richfaces, Myfaces, with an actionListener that defies logic as show in this screen capture:

http://puu.sh/9rOtV/9d59e9fc77.png

Basically, my updateInjury() actionListener has a check after a clientside validation is performed and sets a boolean property validInjury. This check appears to be failing intermittently as shown above where the property, validInjury, is clearly set to false yet the check fails.

The invocation of tomcat 6.0.39 follows:

javaw.exe       0.01    1,441,984 K     790,228 K       499,032 K       39      4000    Java(TM) Platform SE binary     DOC\hkatz       "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:63972 -Xms512M -Xmx1024M "-Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\hkatz\workspace7.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" "-Dcatalina.home=C:\installs\apache-tomcat-6.0.39" "-Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\hkatz\workspace7.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\installs\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\endorsed" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "C:\installs\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\tools.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

No permgen on this instance. How to debug this?

TIA,
Henry

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. It was the ordering of the a4j:actionParam and a4j:commandButton actionListener sequence wreaking havoc here.